# i am trying to merge an audio and a video and save to photos library ios swift

Tags: ios, swift

my audio and video will come from Document directory. Everything is working when i go to save video into photos . but then this error happend and it's not saved.

> failed Optional(Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x17044a2f0 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12842 "(null)"}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-12842), NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed})

here is my  func

```
 func getData(){
        let documentsUrl =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

        do {
            // Get the directory contents urls (including subfolders urls)
            let directoryContents = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentsUrl, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: [])
            print(directoryContents)

            // if you want to filter the directory contents you can do like this:
            videoUrlforMarge = directoryContents.filter{ $0.pathExtension == "mov" } as [AnyObject]
            //videoUrlforMarge.append(directoryContents[1] as AnyObject)
            print("this video \(videoUrlforMarge[0])")

            audioUrl = directoryContents.filter{ $0.pathExtension == "caf" } as [AnyObject]

        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

    }
```

here is my merge func

```
   func mergeFilesWithUrl(videoUrl:NSURL, audioUrl:NSURL)
    {
        let mixComposition : AVMutableComposition = AVMutableComposition()
        var mutableCompositionVideoTrack : [AVMutableCompositionTrack] = []
        var mutableCompositionAudioTrack : [AVMutableCompositionTrack] = []
        let totalVideoCompositionInstruction : AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()


        //start merge



        let aVideoAsset : AVAsset = AVAsset(url: videoUrl as URL)
        let aAudioAsset : AVAsset = AVAsset(url: audioUrl as URL)

        mutableCompositionVideoTrack.append(mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))
        mutableCompositionAudioTrack.append( mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))

        guard aVideoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo).count > 0 && aAudioAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio).count > 0 else{
            return
        }
        let aVideoAssetTrack : AVAssetTrack = aVideoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0]
        let aAudioAssetTrack : AVAssetTrack = aAudioAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio)[0]



        do{
            try mutableCompositionVideoTrack[0].insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, aVideoAssetTrack.timeRange.duration), of: aVideoAssetTrack, at: kCMTimeZero)

            try mutableCompositionAudioTrack[0].insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, aVideoAssetTrack.timeRange.duration), of: aAudioAssetTrack, at: kCMTimeZero)

        }catch{

        }

        totalVideoCompositionInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero,aVideoAssetTrack.timeRange.duration )

        let mutableVideoComposition : AVMutableVideoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
        mutableVideoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30)

        mutableVideoComposition.renderSize = CGSize(width: 1280, height: 720)


        let VideoFilePath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent("mergeVideo\(arc4random()%1000)d")!.appendingPathExtension("mp4").absoluteString
        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: VideoFilePath)

        {
            do

            {
                try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: VideoFilePath)
            }
            catch { }

        }
        let tempfilemainurl =  NSURL(string: VideoFilePath)!
        let sourceAsset = AVURLAsset(url: tempfilemainurl as URL, options: nil)
        let assetExport: AVAssetExportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mixComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality)!
        assetExport.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
        assetExport.outputURL = tempfilemainurl as URL


        assetExport.exportAsynchronously { () -> Void in
            switch assetExport.status
            {
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.completed:
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    do
                    {

                        self.userreponsevideoData = try NSData(contentsOf: tempfilemainurl as URL, options: NSData.ReadingOptions())
                        print("MB - \(self.userreponsevideoData.length) byte")
                        let assetsLib = ALAssetsLibrary()
                        assetsLib.writeVideoAtPath(toSavedPhotosAlbum: tempfilemainurl as URL!, completionBlock: nil)




                    }
                    catch
                    {

                        print(error)
                    }
                })
            case  AVAssetExportSessionStatus.failed:
                print("failed \(String(describing: assetExport.error))")
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.cancelled:
                print("cancelled \(String(describing: assetExport.error))")
            default:
                print("complete")

            }

        }
}
```

and other func i call merge func

```
func Action(){
  guard videoUrlforMarge.count > 0 && audioUrl.count > 0 else{
                return
            }
            let videoUrl  = videoUrlforMarge[0]
            let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: videoUrl.absoluteString!!)
            let audio  = audioUrl[0]
            let urla = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audio.absoluteString!!)

            self.mergeFilesWithUrl(videoUrl: url as NSURL  , audioUrl: 
  urla as NSURL

}
```

Comment: No replay. why why  :(

Comment: Have you added the required warning to the .plist? (Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description) Has the user approved you accessing the photo library?

Comment: yes .. i added this

Answer (score 0):

```
import Photos
import PhotosUI
```

I think you've done a great job providing information and code. It's early Sunday morning here, so maybe the experts are sleeping?  Since your error messages are so cryptic, I'm thinking its a permissions issue, and perhaps you haven't updated your Info.plist to include the "Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description" entry required. Also, when run the first time the user must accept your access request for the save to library to work. [You don't show that code, and none of your code requests (and receives) data from the photos library - which is why I think this is the problem.]
something like this is required:

```
func configureGalleryAccess() {

    PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({(_ status: PHAuthorizationStatus) -> Void in switch status {
        case .authorized:
            print("PHAuthorizationStatusAuthorized")
            self.postAuthorizationLoadController() // replace with your code
        case .denied:
            print("PHAuthorizationStatusDenied")
        case .notDetermined:
            print("PHAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined")
        case .restricted:
            print("PHAuthorizationStatusRestricted")
        }
    })
}
```

The error message is complaining that you are trying to save a nil object which it won't allow. So run the program through the debugger, setting breakpoints before you save the objects/photos. If you find nil where you don't expect it, back up until you find where the problem is. And check for nil before saving when saving an optional.

Comment: is there need any modul import for phphotoLibrary??

Comment: Yes. I added it above: Photos and (possibly - depending on use) PhotosUI

Comment: Still same Problem :(

Comment: it's depending on photos

Comment: Actually when i create a sample project and past this code it's work for 1st time and second time but after few time letter it give this error

Comment: If it works sometimes, then you'll need to set breakpoints to see what is different when you retry.  Let me know what you find out and we can take it from there.

Comment: i was trying to find out by using  break point.  Error occur for this line      
   case  AVAssetExportSessionStatus.failed:
                print("failed \(String(describing: assetExport.error))")